# Markov-like inequality for bias of 0-1 random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $S \subseteq \{0,1\}^d$ for some integer $d$ and let $X_s$ be a random variable over $\{0,1\}$ for every $s \in S$. Define $\omega = \frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{s\in S}\text{bias}(X_s)$, where $\text{bias}(X) = |\Pr(X=0)-\Pr(X=1)|$ for any random variable $X$ over $\{0,1\}$. I don't see how we can use the following claim:

> Let $X$ be a random variable over $[0,1]$ and let $\mu = \mathbb{E}(X)$. Then $\Pr(X \ge \mu/2) \ge \mu/2$.

to argue that there exists a subset $S' \subseteq S$ such that $|S'| \ge \frac{\omega}{2}|S|$.

Comment: The conclusion is trivial because the choice $S'=S$ ensures that $|S'|=|S|\geqslant\frac12\omega|S|$ since $0\le\omega\le1$. Please explain.

Comment: @Did What if $S' \subset S$?